# Thread-safe implementation of the t-digest data structure in Go?

Tags: go, thread-safety

I'm trying to run a benchmark test in Go of a function which I suspect to slow down if more goroutines call it concurrently. I would like to capture P50 and P95 latencies of the function call during the benchmark test using, for example, `github.com/influxdata/tdigest`, like with the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/influxdata/tdigest"
)

func BenchmarkSomething(b *testing.B) {
    concurrencies := []int{1, 10, 30}
    total := 1000

    for _, concurrency := range concurrencies {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("concurrency_%d", concurrency), func(b *testing.B) {
            td := tdigest.New()
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                send := make(chan struct{}, total)
                var wg sync.WaitGroup
                for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go func() {
                        for range send {
                            start := time.Now()
                            duration := time.Duration(int64(rand.NormFloat64()*1e6)) + time.Millisecond
                            time.Sleep(time.Duration(duration))
                            td.Add(float64(time.Since(start)), 1)
                        }
                    }()
                }

                for i := 0; i < total; i++ {
                    send <- struct{}{}
                }
                close(send)
            }
            b.Log("P50 latency:", td.Quantile(0.50))
        })
    }
}
```

However, if I try to run this, I get an `index out of range` error:

```
> go test -bench .
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel
BenchmarkSomething/concurrency_1-8          panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 422 [running]:
github.com/influxdata/tdigest.(*TDigest).updateCumulative(0xc0001b8100)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/influxdata/tdigest@v0.0.1/tdigest.go:154 +0x115
github.com/influxdata/tdigest.(*TDigest).process(0xc0001b8100)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/influxdata/tdigest@v0.0.1/tdigest.go:119 +0x2b0
github.com/influxdata/tdigest.(*TDigest).AddCentroid(0xc0001b8100, 0x413385b200000000, 0x3ff0000000000000)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/influxdata/tdigest@v0.0.1/tdigest.go:85 +0x80
github.com/influxdata/tdigest.(*TDigest).Add(...)
    /Users/kurt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/influxdata/tdigest@v0.0.1/tdigest.go:58
github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel.BenchmarkSomething.func1.1(0xc000271620, 0xc0001b8100)
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel/main_test.go:30 +0x100
created by github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel.BenchmarkSomething.func1
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel/main_test.go:25 +0xa8
exit status 2
FAIL    github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel 0.266s
```

I suspect it is somehow not safe to call this function from multiple goroutines? Is there a way I could get a thread-safe estimator?

### Update

I'm trying to make the code thread-safe by putting all the latencies into a channel, and then calling `td.Add()` for all the latencies in that channel after the benchmark has run. Here is my attempt:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/influxdata/tdigest"
)

func BenchmarkSomething(b *testing.B) {
    concurrencies := []int{1, 10, 30}
    total := 1000

    for _, concurrency := range concurrencies {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("concurrency_%d", concurrency), func(b *testing.B) {
            latencies := make(chan time.Duration, total)
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                send := make(chan struct{}, total)
                var wg sync.WaitGroup
                for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    go func() {
                        for range send {
                            start := time.Now()
                            duration := time.Duration(int64(rand.NormFloat64()*1e6)) + time.Millisecond
                            time.Sleep(time.Duration(duration))
                            latencies <- time.Since(start)
                        }
                    }()
                }

                for i := 0; i < total; i++ {
                    send <- struct{}{}
                }
                close(send)
            }
            td := tdigest.New()
            for latency := range latencies {
                td.Add(float64(latency), 1)
            }
            close(latencies)

            b.Log("P50 latency:", td.Quantile(0.50))
        })
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get a deadlock error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*B).run1(0xc0000ba000, 0xc0000ba000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:251 +0x9e
testing.(*B).Run(0xc0000ba340, 0x11404ff, 0x12, 0x1146e70, 0x10b0400)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:553 +0x2a3
testing.runBenchmarks.func1(0xc0000ba340)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:455 +0x78
testing.(*B).runN(0xc0000ba340, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:176 +0xb3
testing.runBenchmarks(0x1144b57, 0x27, 0xc0000b4060, 0x1237cd0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x60)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:461 +0x39f
testing.(*M).Run(0xc0000dc000, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1078 +0x413
main.main()
    _testmain.go:42 +0x13e

goroutine 5 [chan receive]:
testing.(*B).run1(0xc0000ba4e0, 0xc0000ba4e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:251 +0x9e
testing.(*B).Run(0xc0000ba000, 0xc00001a100, 0xd, 0xc00000c020, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:553 +0x2a3
github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel.BenchmarkSomething(0xc0000ba000)
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel/main_test.go:18 +0x8f
testing.(*B).runN(0xc0000ba000, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:176 +0xb3
testing.(*B).run1.func1(0xc0000ba000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:249 +0x5a
created by testing.(*B).run1
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:242 +0x7d

goroutine 19 [chan receive]:
github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel.BenchmarkSomething.func1(0xc0000ba4e0)
    /Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel/main_test.go:41 +0x1a6
testing.(*B).runN(0xc0000ba4e0, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:176 +0xb3
testing.(*B).run1.func1(0xc0000ba4e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:249 +0x5a
created by testing.(*B).run1
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.12/libexec/src/testing/benchmark.go:242 +0x7d
exit status 2
FAIL    github.com/kurtpeek/send-closed-channel 1.503s
```

Any idea how to make it so that I can call the `td.Add`'s after the test sequentially?

Comment: If a data structure doesn't document it is safe for concurrent access, it generally isn't. Always check concurrent tests with the race detector.

Comment: In second code section, goroutines won't range over send because waiting to write to latencies, but latencies can only start reading after sends have been written. Also, waitgroup appears unused?

Comment: @Mark Indeed there should be a `wg.Wait()` right after `close(latencies)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, I solved this problem by splitting the problem into two steps: sending the latencies to a buffered channel (the required size of the buffer is known up front in this case) and subsequently calling `td.Add()` on the results. This avoids calling `td.Add()` concurrently while still achieving the desired result of measuring the latencies in a concurrent setting.